# In MSA Architecture, Where do I process API responses to client requests?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I wonder about MSA architecture...

In MSA architecture, where do I process API response?

Each separate server directly response to client or gateway server that use each server as module to response to client?

At now, I use second case, but I don't know which one is the better way.

Additional, I use road balancer for combine server. So, for client, Every way looks same.